# Issue after changing sidekiq job type to ActiveJob subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I had a class that initially just included `Sidekiq::Worker`, during some refactoring I made a bonehead move and changed it to a `ActiveJob` subclass and removed the include statement for `Sidekiq::Worker`. Now I get repeat exceptions about `NoMethodError: undefined method 'job_id='`. Is there an easy way to clear out jobs that may be in redis that are causing this issue? I didn't think that it stored the entire job in redis but apparently it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redis-cli flushall` will completely clear out your local Redis.